# Vue.js GoogleMaps API with @googlemaps/js-api-loader

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps-api-3

Thanks for reading my question :)

I'm trying to implement GoogleMaps in my Vue.js project and using the @googlemaps/js-api-loader (from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview#javascript)

My Code looks as follows:

```
<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'
import { Loader } from '@googlemaps/js-api-loader'

const loader = new Loader({
  apiKey: '',
  version: 'weekly',
  libraries: ['places']
})

const map = ref([])

onMounted(async () => {
  await loader
    .load()
    .then(google => {
      map.value = google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
        zoom: 8
      })
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
    .then(function () {
    // always executed
    })
})
</script>

<template>
  <div
    id="map"
    class="map"
  />
</template>

<style>
  html,
  body,
  #map {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>
```

But the map isn't showing, only that pop-up window, that the map can't load properly.
In the console this error occurs:
typeError: this.set is not a function. (In 'this.set("renderingType","UNINITIALIZED")', 'this.set' is undefined)
Does anyone know how to get it running (at best in the `<script setup>`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add **new** like this :

```
map.value = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
        zoom: 8
      })
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought I tried this already but obviously somehow different.

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the width and height in the div with the id map

```
<template>
  <div class="map" id="map" style="width: 300px;height: 200px;" ></div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this too if it didn't work:

```
map.value = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
    zoom: 8
});
```

Comment: Please don't use code snippets for code that won't run.